# How to use delay in source file omnet++

Tags: omnet++

following is the .ned file

```
    simple computer
{
    parameters:

    gates:
        input in1;
        output out1;
        input in2;
        output out2;

}

//
// TODO documentation
//
network Network
{
    @display("bgb=538,302");
    submodules:
        A: computer {
            @display("p=30,88");
        }
        B: computer {
            @display("p=344,96");
        }
        C: computer {
            @display("p=209,199");
        }
    connections:

        A.out1 -->{  delay = 100ms; } --> B.in1;
        B.out1 -->{  delay = 100ms; } --> A.in1;

        A.out2 -->{  delay = 200ms; } --> C.in1;
        C.out1 -->{  delay = 200ms; } --> A.in2;

        C.out2 -->{  delay = 300ms; } --> B.in2;
        B.out2 -->{  delay = 300ms; } --> C.in2;
}



/*
```

* computer.cc
 *
 *  Created on: Sep 29, 2015
 *      Author: Ibrahim
 */

```
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>
#include <string>

double delay1;


class computer: public cSimpleModule
{
  public:


    virtual void initialize();
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg);



};
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

Define_Module(computer);

void computer::initialize()
{

cDelayChannel * channel = check_and_cast<cDelayChannel*>(gate("out1")->getChannel());
    delay1 = channel->getDelay().dbl();


    cMessage *msg = new cMessage("tictocMsg");
         cMessage *ww ; ww=msg;

         send(msg, "out1");
         cMessage *copy = (cMessage *) msg->dup();send(copy, "out2");
```

//I pasted them here as well

```
}

void computer::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{



}
```

my question is that how can I use the delay
*computer0.out -->{  **delay = 100ms**; } --> computer1.in;* 
in .cc file. Here in source file I have two variables delay1 and delay2. I want to move the delay values (100) in delay1 and delay2 variable. how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

An example of reading the value of delay of a channel in OMNeT++ 4.6. 
 NED file:

```
// File: network.ned
simple computer
{
    parameters:
    gates:
        input in1;
        output out1;
        input in2;
        output out2;
}

network Network
{
    @display("bgb=538,302");
    submodules:
        A: computer {
            @display("p=30,88");
        }
        B: computer {
            @display("p=344,96");
        }
        C: computer {
            @display("p=209,199");
        }
    connections:
        A.out1 --> {  delay = 100ms; } --> B.in1;
        B.out1 --> {  delay = 100ms; } --> A.in1;
        A.out2 --> {  delay = 200ms; } --> C.in1;
        C.out1 --> {  delay = 200ms; } --> A.in2;
        C.out2 --> {  delay = 300ms; } --> B.in2;
        B.out2 --> {  delay = 300ms; } --> C.in2;
}
```

Source file:

```
// file: computer.cc
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>
#include <string>

double delay1;

class computer: public cSimpleModule {
public:

    virtual void initialize();
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg);
};

Define_Module(computer);

void computer::initialize() {
    cDelayChannel * channel = check_and_cast<cDelayChannel*>(gate("out1")->getChannel());
    delay1 = channel->getDelay().dbl();
    EV << "delay = " << delay1 << std::endl;
    // other operations...
}

void computer::handleMessage(cMessage *msg) {
}
```

omnetpp.ini file:

```
[General]
network = Network
```

The above cc file was compiled using `OMNeT++ 4.6` for Windows. And here is the log after starting simulation:

```
** Initializing network
Initializing module Network, stage 0
Network.A: Initializing module Network.A, stage 0
Network.A: delay = 0.1
Network.B: Initializing module Network.B, stage 0
Network.B: delay = 0.1
Network.C: Initializing module Network.C, stage 0
Network.C: delay = 0.2
```

Comment: Thank you very very much

Comment: delay1 = channel->getDelay().dbl(); this is causing syntax error

Comment: delay1 = channel->getDelay().dbl(); this is causing syntax error

Comment: I have just checked this code in OMNeT++ 4.6 and it works properly. Could you provide details of syntax error? And could you provide complete ned and cc files?

Comment: I am using multiple gates, you can see my ned and cc file which I am sharing

Comment: ERROR : computer.cc:14:1: error: 'delay1' does not name a type

Comment: Place the three lines inside a method of `computer` class, for example inside `initialize()`.

Comment: i have placed the code in initialize but now the run time error appears which is:

Comment: check_and_cast(): cannot cast null pointer to type 'cDelayChannel*'

Comment: <!> Error in module (computer) Network.A (id=2) during network initialization: check_and_cast(): cannot cast NULL pointer to type 'cDelayChannel *'.

Comment: Could you provide your current cc and ned files?

Comment: The cc file is given above.  Ned is given above as well. I edited my question and pasted thr cc and ned file i am working with

Comment: The cc and ned files i have uploaded are the ones.

Comment: In the cc code in your question the three lines are outside `initialize()`. You wrote that they are inside `initialize()`. So my question is: **where** did you place these lines? It is difficult to help you without knowing code that causes an error...

Comment: void computer::initialize() { cMessage *msg = new cMessage("tictocMsg"); cMessage *ww ; ww=msg; send(msg, "out1"); cMessage *copy = (cMessage *) msg->dup();send(copy, "out2"); here i placed these lines. Even i placed them at the start of initialize function. Outside the class the syntax error appeared but inside the class in the initialize function there code runs no syntax error but runtime error comes saying Error in module (computer) Network.A (id=2) during network initialization: check_and_cast(): cannot cast NULL pointer to type 'cDelayChannel *'.}

Comment: Ok i am uploading the exact cc file for your convenience

Comment: I have placed cc, ned and ini file based on your code in my answer. Everything works properly - the read delay is printed in output log. I have used OMNeT++ 4.6, Windows 7 64-bit. Could you make a new OMNeT++ project and use the code from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

**Hi,
in the net file if you make the connection between nodes in two directions for example node 0 and node 1 :**

```
node[0].gate++ <--> {  delay = 100ms; } <--> node[1].gate++;
```

---

then  you can try  this code in the cc file :

```
  double NodeDelay;

  int n = gateSize("gate");

      for (int i =0;i<n;i++)
     {

     channel = check_and_cast<cDelayChannel*>(gate("gate$o",i)->getChannel());
 

    NodeDelay = channel->getDelay().dbl();

   EV << "hbi delay = " << NodeDelay << endl;

 }
```

**hope it works   **